# How is GROUP BY eliminating records? - Leetcode 1084 Sales Analysis III

Tags: mysql

Leetcode question 1084: Sales Analysis III

Write an SQL query that reports the products that were only sold in the first quarter of 2019. That is, between 2019-01-01 and 2019-03-31 inclusive.

Return the result table in any order.

```
Product table:
+------------+--------------+------------+
| product_id | product_name | unit_price |
+------------+--------------+------------+
| 1          | S8           | 1000       |
| 2          | G4           | 800        |
| 3          | iPhone       | 1400       |
+------------+--------------+------------+
Sales table:
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+
| seller_id | product_id | buyer_id | sale_date  | quantity | price |
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+
| 1         | 1          | 1        | 2019-01-21 | 2        | 2000  |
| 1         | 2          | 2        | 2019-02-17 | 1        | 800   |
| 2         | 2          | 3        | 2019-06-02 | 1        | 800   |
| 3         | 3          | 4        | 2019-05-13 | 2        | 2800  |
+-----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+
Output: 
+-------------+--------------+
| product_id  | product_name |
+-------------+--------------+
| 1           | S8           |
+-------------+--------------+
```

**My answer is with the simple nested query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id, product_name

FROM Product JOIN Sales USING(product_id)

WHERE product_id NOT IN
    (SELECT product_id
    FROM Sales
    WHERE sale_date > '2019-03-31')

GROUP BY product_id

HAVING MIN(sale_date) >= '2019-01-01' AND MAX(sale_date) <= '2019-03-31'
```

**However, there is a different solution that I saw in the discussion:**

```
select s.product_id, p.product_name

from sales s, product p

where s.product_id = p.product_id

group by s.product_id, p.product_name

having min(s.sale_date) >= '2019-01-01' 
    and max(s.sale_date) <= '2019-03-31'
```

**Could anyone help me understand why and how the 2nd solution works?**

Comment: the second solution is a straightforward implementation of what the question asks.  maybe tell us what you think your subquery is helping do?

Comment: `Sales` is a fact table that is joined with a dimension, so essentially the query works on `Sales`. Now, it searches for any `product_id` which sales are ONLY in the requested date range.

Comment: Your solution should also work, albeit with minor changes: 1) Change the first line to `SELECT product_id, max(product_name)`; 2) Remove the last line (`HAVING`).

Comment: @TheImpaler 3) add`OR sale_date < '2019-01=01'` to the subquery.  re 1), this isn't necessary for some versions of mysql, and also grouping by name is another alternative (as in the second solution).  DISTINCT is not ever useful with group by, though.

Comment: @ysth Thank you so much for your advice! I intended to use sub-query to eliminate the products that are sold after the first quarter of 2019. 
I would love to hear from you how the second solution is able to choose products that are only sold in the first quarter of 2019.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you very much for your detailed advice! I learned a lot. Could you help me understand why we are using MAX(product_name)? And I would appreciate it if you can help me explain how the second solution can choose the products that are sold ONLY in the first quarter of 2019?

Comment: The second query computes the min and max dates for the sales of each product. Then it makes sure they are no sales outside the quarter.

Comment: to see how it works, try just `select s.product_id, p.product_name, min(s.sale_date),max(s.sale_date) from product p join sales s using (product_id) group by s.product_id` (basically the 2nd solution without the having) and note that the ones the having will exclude are the ones with sales outside the quarter.

from sales s, product p

where s.product_id = p.product_id

group by s.product_id, p.product_name